# How to get OUT parameter by executing stored procedure in CMD @echo , ORALCE-PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cmd

> Procedure structure :: Package.Procedure(In a,Out b)

---

> @echo execute Package.Procedure('%a%',**?XX?**) | sqlplus
>   %USER_ID%/%PASSWORD%@%SID%

---

I can execute procedure with IN parameters or without parameters.
I would like to know how can I do for OUT parameter.

****  ITS INSIDE CMD, NOT SQLPLUS  ****

Comment: The fact that you are using the windows shell to build the PL/SQL stattement is mostly irrelevant as it is being piped into SQL/Plus and run there (the windows shell cannot parse SQL and does not know your databases). So **any** code that can be run in SQL/Plus can be used as you just need to echo it and pipe it through so it can be parsed by the SQL client.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation..So is there any way to work with procedure by using only cmd batch file..!!

Answer (score 1):

Just another variation for execution. Tried executing the whole block from CMD and I guess this is working.

```
SET AUTOPRINT ON;
var out_param VARCHAR2(100); -- Bind Variable
EXEC Package.Procedure('Input_param',:out_param);

----------------------------------FROM CMD--------------------------------------

C:\windows\system32>@ECHO DECLARE my_num NUMBER; AVROY.TEST_CMD(my_num);dbms_out
put.put_line(my_num); END; |sqlplus <username>/<password>@SID
```

Comment: Plz chck if this helps.

Comment: In CMD code , where you are getting output? (dbms_out
put.put_line(my_num);) for this..

Answer (score 0):

A way is to write a block of PL/SQL code as following:

```
DECLARE
    var NUMBER;
BEGIN
    Package.Procedure('%a%',var);
    dbms_output.put_line(var);
END;
```

Comment: You can write it inside SQL Plus and terminate it with / character, or save it in a text file and launch it with SQL Plus using sqlplus @file.txt

Comment: I know to write it with sqlPlus , i want to know for CMD. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In SQLPlus command prompt, you can write something like below

```
variable z NUMBER
BEGIN
    Package.Procedure('%a%', :z);
END;

You should get "Procedure executed successfully"
```

and than

```
print z;
```

you should get value

OR an alternate

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    z NUMBER;
BEGIN
    Package.Procedure('%a%',z);
    dbms_output.put_line(z);
END;
```

Comment: So u want to call the Proc without using any Oracle client like sqlplus,sql developer. It should be via CMD?

Comment: `DECLARE z NUMBER;` does not declare a bind variable it declares a PL/SQL variable so you cannot reference it as `:z` and you will get `SP2-0552: Bind variable "Z" not declared.`.